# Sonic Origins (2022 video game compilation) for Xbox Series S vs. homemade Raspberry (retro gaming distro)

Tags: version-differences, xbox-series-x-series-s, sonic-origins

My toddler plays *Sonic Origins* on Xbox Series S. She used to play the same game on Apple TV. I had to buy/license the game twice. In general, my toddler likes so-called retro games, i.e. games that don't have contemporary graphics.

For me as a layman the game "Sonic Origins" looks like it was made in the 80s and was only minimally adapted/reworked for the Xbox Series S. Am I seeing this correctly or was there much more done that I don't notice?

I wonder if I should not rather use a gaming distro for the Raspberry. There is RetroPie, Recalbox, Lakka or Batocera for retro gaming on the Raspberry Pi. According to a Youtube video the ROMs are a legal grey area. But please no legal discussion, that is not the question in this posting.

Is it worth buying refurbished classic games for Xbox and other modern platforms? What is the difference in "Sonic Origins" for Xbox Series S vs. on Raspberry with retro gaming distro?

Answer (score 1):

> For me as a layman the game "Sonic Origins" looks like it was made in the 80s and was only minimally adapted/reworked for the Xbox Series S. Am I seeing this correctly or was there much more done that I don't notice?

*Sonic Origins* is a remaster of four games which were originally released in the 90's. It is intended to provide an authentic experience similar to actually playing the original games, with a few additions/concessions:

- There is now a widescreen mode to fit modern aspect ratios. If this is not used, then the games run in 4:3 with vertical borders (i.e. pillarboxed).
- You can play without lives.
- There is a fair amount of bonus content and alternate game modes that were not available in the original games, including animated cutscenes explaining the games' stories (I'm not specifically familiar with the early Sonic games, but I assume this is meant as a replacement for [the manuals](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AllThereInTheManual)).

It is not intended to look or play like a modern game, so it probably doesn't look visually impressive by today's standards.

> Is it worth buying refurbished classic games for Xbox and other modern platforms? What is the difference in "Sonic Origins" for Xbox Series S vs. on Raspberry with retro gaming distro?

I am not allowed to answer that question, because [we do not answer questions about pirated games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But even if I was, it would still be off-topic as too subjective (only you know how much your money is worth).